# MoveIt! with Gazebo, using MoveItSimpleControllerManager, joint_trajectory_controller

Tags: gazebo, moveit, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use MoveIt! to control a simulated robot in Gazebo, and am at a loss as to how to proceed. The only documentation / tutorial I can find on the subject is [this one](http://picknik.io/moveit_wiki/index.php?title=PR2/Gazebo/Quick_Start), which is 4 years old and works only for a specific robot, that comes with all the necessary controllers.

**My understanding so far:**

- The MoveItSimpleControllerManager plugin should 'convert' MoveIt! executions to FollowJointTrajectory action calls. I have included the plugin in myrobot_moveit_controller_manager.launch (adapted from the demo.launch generated by the MoveIt! setup assistant) with:

  ```
    <!-- Set the param that trajectory_execution_manager needs to find the controller plugin -->
    <arg name="moveit_controller_manager" default="moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager" />
    <param name="moveit_controller_manager" value="$(arg moveit_controller_manager)"/>

    <arg name="controller_manager_name" default="moveit_simple_controller_manager" />
    <param name="controller_manager_name" value="$(arg controller_manager_name)" />

    <arg name="use_controller_manager" default="true" />
    <param name="use_controller_manager" value="$(arg use_controller_manager)" />

    <!-- load controller_list -->
    <rosparam file="$(find myrobot_moveit_config)/config/controllers.yaml"/>
  ```
- The joint_trajectory_controller from ros_controllers should implement the action server required for the FollowJointTrajectory calls, and actuate the joints in Gazebo accordingly via the libgazebo_ros_control plugin for Gazebo. I am trying to spawn the controller with:

  ```
    <node name="controller_spawner"
          pkg="controller_manager"
          type="spawner"
          respawn="false"
          output="screen"
          ns="/myrobot"
          args="joint_state_controller joint_trajectory_controller"/>
  ```

**The problem:**

When I run the above launch files as well as the Gazebo one (which also uploads the robot description to the param server), I get the following output in the MoveIt! terminal:

```
[FATAL] [1498731799.850090680, 16.100000000]: Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager' not specified. This is needed to identify the plugin to use for interacting with controllers. No paths can be executed.
```

I'm using ROS Indigo with Ubuntu 14.04.

Could some-one let me know if my overall understanding is flawed, and what might cause the above error message?

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

I fixed the above error message by putting the first set of XML tags inside the namespace of the move_group node, with:

```
<group ns="move_group"> ... </group>
```

Now the controller manager seems to be connected, but I get the following error messages. When I start the MoveIt! node:

```
[ERROR] [1498747248.394583362, 16.231000000]: MoveItSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: arm_r_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
```

And when I attempt to execute a trajectory:

```
[ERROR] [1498747328.213270503, 70.727000000]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ ... ]
```

It was my understanding that MoveItSimpleControllerManager was the 'action client' - is this wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265138/moveit!-with-gazebo,-using-moveitsimplecontrollermanager,-joint_trajectory_controller/) by [PhydeauxLeChien](https://answers.ros.org/users/30958/phydeauxlechien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-06-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PhydeauxLeChien](https://answers.ros.org/users/30958/phydeauxlechien/) on 2017-06-29**:
If anyone could help with formatting XML in questions as well, that'd be great. The < param > tags don't seem to be displaying >.<

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-29**:
Use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it). Keep in mind that when formatting text that is part of a list, you'll have to increase indentation level (ie: prefix more spaces), as it's relative to the indentation level of the surrounding text.

**Comment by [PhydeauxLeChien](https://answers.ros.org/users/30958/phydeauxlechien/) on 2017-06-29**:
Thanks - the list thing, that's what I was missing.

**Comment by [yyf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29997/yyf/) on 2017-09-27**:
Have you solved the problem:MoveItSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: arm_r_controller/follow_joint_trajectory? I have the same trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that your MoveIt controller manager expects a ROS action at `arm_r_controller/follow_joint_trajectory`,
but that does not exist. run `rostopic list | grep goal` and find the FollowTrajectoryAction that is setup with your gazebo ros_control plugin.

You can either change the topic in the gazebo configuration or in the controllers.yaml.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0